# Multiple Ansible connection for diferent task in the same playbook

Tags: ansible

I have the next main.yml

```yaml
- name: Install ncpa
  import_tasks: windows_ncpa.yml
  when: ansible_facts['os_family']|lower == 'windows'

- name: Register XI
  import_tasks: register_with_xi.yml
```

I am triyinng to launch two ansible playbooks, but each one needs diferent ansible connections,
The first one uses WINRM and works correctly:

```yaml
- name: Create download directory
  win_file:
    path: C:\\tmp
    state: directory

- name: Copy the executable package to download directory
  win_copy:
    src: software/ncpa-2.4.1.exe
    dest: 'C:\tmp\ncpa-2.4.1.exe'

- name: Install NCPA
  win_package:
    path: 'C:\tmp\ncpa-2.4.1.exe'
    arguments: /S /TOKEN='{{ ncpa_token }}'
    product_id: '{ncpa}'

- name: Restart NCPA
  win_service:
    name: ncpalistener
    state: restarted
```

But the second task needs ssh connections because is a Linux machine:

```yaml
---
- name: Register Host
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ xi_ip }}/nagiosxi/api/v1/config/host?apikey={{ xi_api_key }}"
    body: 'host_name={{ ansible_fqdn }}&address={{ ansible_fqdn }}&check_command=check-host-alive&max_check_attempts=32&check_period=24x7&contacts=nagiosadmin&notification_interval=25&notification_period=24x7&hostgroups=grp_so_windows&alias=Consola para soporte sistemas&use=t_host_windows,t_host_ncpa_token1&applyconfig=1&force=1'
    method: POST
    validate_certs: no
```

And I don't know how to do it, i used the module reset_connection, but I have not achieved anything, always uses first connection

```
TASK [ncpa_install_windows : Register Host] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: */ncpa_install_windows/tasks/register_with_xi.yml:2
<*> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible on PORT 5986 TO *
fatal: [*]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "kerberos: authGSSClientStep() failed: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377))",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

I tried the next method (the common.yml contains the ssh connection) and anything

```yaml
- name: Register Host
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/common.yml
  connection: local
  become: true
  become_user: devopsys
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ xi_ip }}/nagiosxi/api/v1/config/host?apikey={{ xi_api_key }}"
    body: >
      host_name={{ ansible_fqdn }}
      &address={{ ansible_fqdn }}
      &check_command=check-host-alive
      &max_check_attempts=32
      &check_period=24x7
      &contacts=nagiosadmin
      &notification_interval=25
      &notification_period=24x7
      &hostgroups=grp_so_windows
      &alias=Consola para soporte sistemas
      &use=t_host_windows,t_host_ncpa_token1
      &applyconfig=1
    method: POST
    validate_certs: no
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I relaunched the code again and it works!

In this case, the `delegate_to: localhost` keyword it has worked!